# Why is a struct member uninitialized after dereferencing the struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm writing an `HBridge` class to make handling HBridges one arduino much easier. I'm not sure why I call `.print()` on my HBridge instance, it prints:

```
---------
BRIDGE ONE
Bridge Use:->pin: 1392293344
Bridge Idle->pin: 1392293408
Freq:0
Dir:0
---------
BRIDGE TWO
Bridge Use:->pin: 8
Bridge Idle->pin: 214125355
Freq:0
Dir:0
```

Notice how the `Bridge Use` and `Bridge Idle` is uninitialized. Am I making a mistake somewhere with my pointers?

Here is my code.

#### HBridge.h

```
//-----------------------|
#define true 1         //|
#define false 0        //|
//-----------------------|
#define PIN_OFF 0      //|
#define PIN_ON  1      //|
//-----------------------|
#define PIN_FORWARD 0 //|
#define PIN_BACKWARD 1//|
//-----------------------|



typedef struct{
    int pin;
} Pin;

typedef struct {
    Pin *inuse;
    Pin *idle;
    int freq;
    int direction;
}Bridge;

typedef enum{ A, B} hbridge_pins;

class HBridge {
    private:
    Bridge bridge_a, bridge_b;
    Bridge *pins[2];
    public:
        HBridge(int, int, int, int);
        void setPinFrequency(hbridge_pins, int);
        void setPinDir(hbridge_pins, int);
        void turnPinOFF(hbridge_pins);
        void update(void);
        void print();
};
```

#### HBridge.cpp

```
#import "./HBridge.h"
#import <stdio.h>


Pin pinWith(int num) {
    // pinMode(num, OUTPUT);
    Pin p;
    p.pin = num;
    return p;
}

void swap_pins(Pin *a, Pin *b) {
        Pin temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}

void print_pin(const char * name, Pin *p){
    printf("%s->pin: %d\n",name,p->pin);
}
void print_bridge(Bridge *b){
    print_pin("Bridge Use:", b->inuse);
    print_pin("Bridge Idle", b->idle);
    printf("Freq:%d\nDir:%d\n",b->freq,b->direction);

}

void HBridge::turnPinOFF(hbridge_pins pin) {
    pins[pin]->freq = PIN_OFF;
}

HBridge::HBridge(int pinAA, int pinAB, int pinBA, int pinBB) {

    Pin a_use = pinWith(pinAA);
    Pin a_idle = pinWith(pinAB); 
    Pin b_use = pinWith(pinBA);
    Pin b_idle = pinWith(pinBB);


    bridge_a.inuse = &a_use;
    bridge_a.idle = &a_idle;

    bridge_b.inuse = &b_use;
    bridge_b.idle = &b_idle;
    



    /*---(DEFAULT DIRECTIONS)---*/
    bridge_a.direction = PIN_FORWARD;
    bridge_b.direction = PIN_FORWARD;
    bridge_a.freq = PIN_OFF;
    bridge_b.freq = PIN_OFF;
    
    /*---(ARRAY OF POINTERS TO THE TWO PINS FOR EASY ACCESS BY INDEX)---*/
    pins[0] =&bridge_a;
    pins[1] =&bridge_b;
}

void HBridge::setPinFrequency(hbridge_pins pin, int freq) {
    pins[pin]->freq = freq;
}

void HBridge::setPinDir(hbridge_pins pin, int dir) {
    if ((pins[pin]->direction == PIN_FORWARD && dir == PIN_FORWARD) || (pins[pin]->direction == PIN_BACKWARD && dir == PIN_BACKWARD)) {
        
    } else if (pins[pin]->direction == PIN_FORWARD && dir == PIN_BACKWARD) {
        
        /*----(SWAP POINTERS)----*/
        swap_pins(pins[pin]->inuse, pins[pin]->idle);
        pins[pin]->direction = PIN_BACKWARD;
        
    } else if (pins[pin]->direction == PIN_BACKWARD && dir == PIN_FORWARD) {
        
        /*----(SWAP POINTERS)----*/
        swap_pins(pins[pin]->inuse, pins[pin]->idle);
        pins[pin]->direction = PIN_BACKWARD;
        
    }
}

void HBridge::update(void)/*pointer to an int to save memory*/ {
    /*THE FIRST BRIDGE*/
    // analogWrite(pins[0]->inuse->pin, pins[0]->freq);
    // analogWrite(pins[0]->indle->pin, pins[0]->PIN_OFF);

    // THE SECOND BRIDGE
    // analogWrite(pins[1]->inuse->pin, pins[1]->freq);
    // analogWrite(pins[1]->indle->pin, pins[1]->PIN_OFF);
} 

void HBridge::print(void){

    printf("---------\nBRIDGE ONE\n");
    print_bridge(pins[0]);

    printf("---------\nBRIDGE TWO\n");
    print_bridge(pins[1]);
}


int main(int argc, const char*argv[]){
    HBridge b(31,42,33,4);
    b.setPinFrequency(A,200);
    b.print();
}
```

Comment: `Bridge` should have a constructor that initializes the pointers to `nullptr`.

Comment: Ew! This is C++, and 2015. Why the `malloc` and `memcpy`?

Comment: Don't `#define` true and false! They are language keywords.

Comment: If you're going to write C++, you need to unlearn all your old C idioms, like `typedef struct { } name;` Just do `struct name { };` Stop using malloc(). Prefer make_unique<>() or make_shared<>() if you actually need dynamic memory.

Comment: @RobK Thanks for alerting me to this. I'm only about 6 hours into my C++, and am not yet well acquainted will all the features of its standard library. Lesson: before implementing, something, check the docs to see what conventional language X programmers do.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into the question. Instead, post an answer . I have rolled back the question so you can do this (copy-paste out of the edit history if you need to).

Answer (score 2):

`Pin a_use` is local to the constructor and you are making a pointer from it, although it will be deallocated when the contsructor returns.

Declare `inuse` and `idle` as `Pin inuse;` and `Pin idle;` and don't make a pointer, just assign to them what `pinWith()` returns, the value will be copied and the problem will be gone.

If you need them to be pointers, then first request heap space like this

```
bridge_a.inuse = new Pin;
```

and then do this

```
memcpy(bridge_a.inuse, &a_use, sizeof(Pin));
```

if the `Pin` doesn't contain any class but just [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146454/1983495) fields, it will work, otherwise a more elaborated copy will be needed.

Comment: @theideasmith Inside `HBridge`, change `Bridge *pins[2];` to `Bridge pins[2];` (remove the pointer), then in the constructor remove the ampersands in the assignment to `a_use`, `a_idle`, `b_use`, `b_idle`. If you have to take a pointer in `print`, pass the address (`print(&pin[0]); print(&pin[1])` but you really should instead take a reference to a `Bridge` and use `.` instead of `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @iharob.  You have the same problem in the `pinWith()` function where you return a `Pin` off the stack for the `pinWith()` function, a position which becomes "garbage" once you return from the function.  You'll need to allocate a `Pin` from the heap in `pinWith()` to fix this.

```
Pin pinWith(int num) {
    // pinMode(num, OUTPUT);
    Pin p = new Pin;
    p.pin = num;
    return p;
}
```